# Text color changes on button, but not every time

Tags: javascript, html, css

okay, so I'm new here and maybe I'm just tired from how long this has confused me, but here we go: 
On a button click: 
When the variable "GPA" is below 2.5, the text "finalText" should turn red. When it's 2.5 or above, it should turn green. I'm using bootstrap, and I've tried any number of solutions here. One thing that kept happening was that the color would change, but If I tried again, and the GPA was still in the same range, the color would cancel out. (i.e. if I entered 1 and GPA = 0.0, and then I entered 3 and the GPA was still 0.0, The text would change to red the first time, but change back to black the second time.)

EDIT - okay i fixed the reverting to default, but if it changes to red it can't go back to green... any thoughts?

https://jsfiddle.net/turtlebox1/ze1c5uxr/#&togetherjs=jR3i9EqGne

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>BIT 116</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style>
.jumbotron {
 /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#9ee8fa+0,d6f9ff+100 */
 background: rgb(158,232,250); /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(158,232,250,1) 0%, rgba(214,249,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(158,232,250,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(214,249,255,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(158,232,250,1) 0%,rgba(214,249,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(158,232,250,1) 0%,rgba(214,249,255,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(158,232,250,1) 0%,rgba(214,249,255,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(158,232,250,1) 0%,rgba(214,249,255,1) 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#9ee8fa', endColorstr='#d6f9ff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<!-- the 'fluid' container should span the width of the page -->
<div class="container-fluid" >

<div class="page-header">

 <div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>Melia Taylor</h1></div>
<!-- Horizontal list of menus across the top: -->
</div>

    <h2 class="text-center" id="greeting">greeting</h2>
 <h3 class="text-center">GPA Calculator</h3>
    <br/>
    <form>
    <p>Please Enter your grade (In the format "93" for 93%, etc.)</p>
    <input type="text" id="gradeInput">
    <input type="button" id="feedback" value="Click Here To See Your GPA!">
    </form>
    
    <p id="finalText">finaltext</p>
</div> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var gradeV;
    
    var GPA;
    
    var colorCheck;
    
    var color;
    
    $("#greeting").hide();
    
    $("#finalText").hide();
    
    function midGrades(gradeV) {
                    return (((gradeV-65) * .1 ) + 1);
                console.log(midGrades(gradeV));
                }
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var nameString = prompt("What is your name?", "");
        
        console.log(nameString);
        
            if(nameString == null || nameString === "")
            {
                console.log("Name is null or undefined");
            }
            else {
            document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = ("Welcome to TellMeMyGrade, " + nameString + "!");
            $("#greeting").show();
            alert("Welcome to TellMeMyGrade, " + nameString + "!");
            }
    });
    
    color = document.getElementById("finalText");  
           $("#feedback").click(function() {

        var grade = ($("#gradeInput").val());
        
          
        gradeV = parseFloat(grade);
          
        console.log(gradeV);
          
            if(gradeV <= 0 || isNaN(gradeV) || (Math.floor(gradeV) <= 0))
            {
                alert("Please re-enter your grade in the correct format.");
            }
          
            if((gradeV > 0) && (gradeV < 62))
            {
               $("#finalText").hide(); document.getElementById("finalText").innerHTML = ("Your Grade for this class is a 0.0");
               GPA = 0.0;
        $("#finalText").show();
            }
          
          
          if((gradeV >=62) && (gradeV <= 65))
            {
                 $("#finalText").hide();
                document.getElementById("finalText").innerHTML = ("Your Grade for this class is a 1.0");
               
                GPA = 1.0;
            $("#finalText").show();
            }
            if((gradeV > 65) && (gradeV < 95))
            {
                $("#finalText").hide();
                document.getElementById("finalText").innerHTML = ("Your Grade for this class is a " + midGrades(gradeV).toFixed(1));
                 
               GPA = midGrades(gradeV);
                $("#finalText").show();
            }
             if(gradeV >= 95) 
            {
               $("#finalText").hide(); document.getElementById("finalText").innerHTML = ("Your Grade for this class is a 4.0");
               
                GPA = 4.0;
                $("#finalText").show();
            }
          
                      
             console.log("GPA: " + GPA);
          
          if(GPA < 2.5)
        //above a 2.5 is considered non-danger zone, to me.
          {
            console.log("danger");
              console.log(colorCheck);
             if (colorCheck != "red")
            { 
            color.classList.toggle("text-danger"); 
            colorCheck = "red";
                console.log(colorCheck);
            }
          }
          else
            {
              console.log("success");
                console.log(colorCheck);
              if (colorCheck != "green") {
              color.classList.toggle("text-success"); 
              colorCheck = "green";
                  console.log(colorCheck);
          }
            
          }
        
    });
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be great, if you can share a fiddle of your code. It will be easier to help you in that case

Comment: @JeevanMB I did:)

Answer (score 0):

Your class has both text-danger and text-success. You must toggle text-danger to remove it as well.

```
        if(GPA < 2.5)
    //above a 2.5 is considered non-danger zone, to me.
      {
        console.log("danger");
          console.log(colorCheck);
         if (colorCheck != "red")
        { 
        color.classList.toggle("text-danger"); 
        colorCheck = "red";
            console.log(colorCheck);
        }
      }
      else
        {
          console.log("success");
            console.log(colorCheck);
          if (colorCheck != "green") {
            color.classList.toggle("text-danger"); 
            color.classList.toggle("text-success"); 
          colorCheck = "green";
              console.log(colorCheck);
      }
        }
```

Comment: how? I mean, I tried to implement that, but it caused more issues.. could I get an example?

Comment: that seems to make the first test on success wrong. (if i test it with '99' it displays in red when it should in green)

Comment: It was toggling the danger class as well, which was overriding success again. Try:
          if(GPA < 2.5) {
            if (colorCheck != "red" || colorCheck == ""){ 
                $(color).removeClass("text-success"); 
                $(color).addClass("text-danger"); 
                colorCheck = "red";
            }
          } else {
              if (colorCheck != "green") {
                  $(color).removeClass("text-danger"); 
                  $(color).addClass("text-success"); 
                  colorCheck = "green";
              }            
          }

Answer (score 0):

You are not removing `text-danger`. Remove this or else it will overwrite `text-success`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! I had to toggle `text-danger` off, and conditionally consider the variable of the color before changing it or toggling anything. Here is the changed piece of code:

```js
if (!isNaN(GPA)) {
          if(GPA < 2.5)
        //above a 2.5 is considered non-danger zone, to me.
          {
            console.log("danger");
              console.log(colorCheck);
              
             if (colorCheck != "red")
            { 
                if (colorCheck != "green")
                {
                    color.classList.toggle("text-danger"); 
                    colorCheck = "red";
                    console.log(colorCheck + "1");
                }
                else {
                    color.classList.toggle("text-success");
                    color.classList.toggle("text-danger"); 
                    colorCheck = "red";
                    console.log(colorCheck);
                }
            }
          }
          else
            {
              console.log("success");
                console.log(colorCheck);
                
              if (colorCheck != "green") 
              {
                  if (colorCheck != "red")
                  {
                      color.classList.toggle("text-success"); 
                       colorCheck = "green";
                       console.log(colorCheck + "1");  
                  }
                  else {
                  color.classList.toggle("text-danger");
                  color.classList.toggle("text-success"); 
                  colorCheck = "green";
                  console.log(colorCheck);
                  }
                  return colorCheck;
              }
              return colorCheck;
          }
              return colorCheck;
          }
        
    });
```